# HTML Email Responsive

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, html-email

Hi everyone I would like to create two versions of my code one for desktop and another for mobile.

This is because I need to change some texts and images to mobile respect desktop version.

As an example of what I tried.

If anyone knows how I can do solve this, please help me.

```html
<style>
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  <!-- Small devices -->@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile {
      display: block;
    }
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="desktop">
    <table bgcolor="#0d0d0d" width="620" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#0d0d0d" align="center">
          <table align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d">
                <!--Image Version 1 Desktop -->
                <img src="CarImage_v1.png" style="display:block; border:0" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d">
                <!-- Car Text  Version 1 Desktop -->
                <p style="font-family: Arial; color:#c2c2c2; font-size:20px;">
                  Superior en todo. <br/> Incluso en clase.
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile">
    <table bgcolor="#0d0d0d" width="620" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d">
                <!--Image Version 2 Mobile -->
                <img src="CarImage_v2.png" style="display:block; border:0" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#0d0d0d">
                <!-- Car Text Version 2 Mobile -->
                <p style="font-family: Arial; color:#c2c2c2; font-size:20px;">
                  Cuando la deportividad y <br/> la clase se entiende
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

--- What I want ----

Desktop version

[image]

Mobile version

[image]

Comment: "I would like to create two versions of my code one for desktop and another for mobile." - **you can't and you shouldn't** because you don't know if your HTML email will be opened on a mobile device or a desktop/laptop.

Comment: You are aware that Desktop Outlook's HTML rendering is awful, frozen in time since 2007?

Comment: Hi @Dai, you're right, but if I would like to change text version and image from mobile and desktop, how could I do?

Comment: What, exactly, are you changing, and why? Why can't the same image be used in both cases?

Comment: First of all @Dai, in my example I have one image with its text in desktop version, so when newsletter displays mobile version I need to change that previous image for a new one and its text.

Comment: Yes, you've already explained that - but you haven't explained _why_ you want to use a different image and text for mobile vs. desktop. I cannot think of a good reason why it should be different. All you should be doing is changing the _layout_ and styling - not the content.

Comment: Regarding image and I should do it, because I have to add a bigger image for a mobile than a desktop, and regarding text I'm gonna post a picture what I want because you won't understand me..

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a _bigger image_ for desktop vs mobile though. But yes, an illustration will help.,

Comment: Hi again @Dai, I think in my case I need it, however you have available both images.

Comment: That's the same image, just scaled and cropped. You can do that with a single image and CSS.

Comment: @Dai What about text?  is it possible to do it?

Comment: Yes, just use `display: none;` for the text you want to hide. Do not use `content:` because that's inaccessible.

Comment: Just like that?  but if you hide this text you will hide in both versions, will you?

Comment: That's what the `@media` block is for.

Comment: `@media` is very poor: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40media

Comment: @tacoshy That's not my interpretation. On the contrary, `@media` support is great, the only problem being Desktop Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

[As of late 2021, you can safely use `@media` in HTML emails' stylesheets](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=media) to alter the style, layout, and to an extent: the content, of a HTML email based on the email software's viewport size - which serves as an adequate proxy for the mobile vs. desktop use-cases.

<sub>Note that as of November 2021 the CanIEmail.com page linked above currently describes 36% e-mail programs *fully* supporting `@media` rules, and the next 39% of e-mail programs only *partially* supporting `@media` (but they still support what we need: `min/max-width`). That's only 75% support... *however*: we only need *all mobile e-mail apps* to support `@media`: it doesn't matter if a desktop e-mail app supports it or not - so that's why it's OK to use it.</sub>

The only hold-out is Office Outlook for the Windows desktop, but that's fine as you can make the "desktop" version the default in your stylesheet.

Something like this:

```css
img {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #c2c2c2;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* By default, assume a desktop browser or e-mail client: */
/* (As all mobile e-mail viewers do support (at least basic) CSS media queries. */

.mobileOnly {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
/* Assume mobile devices are < 768px wide (as the original iPad in portrait was 768px wide, I assume you want desktop view for large tablets) */

    
    .desktopOnly {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobileOnly {
        display: block;
    }
    span.mobileOnly {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="desktopOnly">
    <img src="CarImage_v1.png" />
    <p>Superior en todo. <br/> Incluso en clase.</p>
</div>

<div class="mobileOnly">
    <img src="CarImage_v2.png" />
    <p>Cuando la deportividad y <br/> la clase se entiende</p>
</div>
```

---

However, as I mentioned in the comments, you don't need to have separate `<img />` and text content for each device. In your case the image itself looks the same, just zoomed and cropped, in which case use `object-fit` in the `img` rule in your small-screen `@media` section. And the text can be controlled with `<span>`:

```
img#carImage {
    object-fit: contain;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    
    img#carImage {
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

Also consider using `transform: scale` and `clip` for additional effects.

...and text can be visible/hidden using `<span class="mobileOnly">`, like so:

```
<div>
    <img id="carImage" src="CarImage.png" />
    <p>
        <span class="desktopOnly">Superior en todo. <br/> Incluso en clase.</span>
        <span class="mobileOnly">Cuando la deportividad y <br/> la clase se entiende</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, in my understanding it's possible to link media queries to outlook desktop?, because it seems doesn't work

Comment: @javi-ur96 No, you still cannot use `@media` in Desktop Outlook **but it doesn't matter** because the stylesheet in my answer treats desktop _as the default_ and only switches mobile/small-screen layout if the e-mail app/browser supports `@media` - and all mobile devices _do support it_. That's why it works.

Answer (score -3):

@javi-ur96,

As I understand all you want is to do is to display the mobile version or the Desktop version depending on the screen size.

You can use `javaScripts` function and just make use of the `else if` condition to render the page depending on the screen size.

but I don't think it is a good practice. Instead go with the below options.

1. Make use of the grid property to make the same content become responsive. So you will SAVE a whole lot of file size and coding.

   You can find great examples in this [LINK](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/) to suit your needs.
2. Instead of switching the div elements w.r.t desktop or mobile, create just one version of it and try to switch their properties depending on the screen size.

You can find example links below:

1. [Typical Media Query Breakpoints](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery_breakpoints)
   You can also display images of different sizes as you need.
2. [Responsive Web Design using Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
   This shows you how you should build your website.

Comment: This question is specifically tagged as html-email. You should realize, that JS is poorly supported by email clients. A large portion of clients (Outlook, Windows 10 mail, microsoft office, gmail imap app, T-online and AOL) do not support media queries either. So none part of your answer is helpful in this question (espacially since OP already tried using medi queries).

Comment: @tacoshy All official GMail clients support basic `@media` rules. The only e-mail programs that don't support `@media` queries are all desktop browsers (Outlook 2007-2019, Windows 10 Mail (and who uses that?)), so using `@media` to target mobile/phone/small-screen devices is perfectly acceptable. There are other minority holdouts like ProtonMail, but ProtonMail users likely have HTML e-mail entirely disabled so that's moot.